# remove the last two spaces from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

If the length of my string is 30. I got to remove the last 2 spaces from the string.

If the length of my string is 29.I got to remove the last space from the string.

Eg. `COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73` should be `COADC Cathy & Ralph WardJr73`
and not `COADCCathy&RalphWardJr73`

Tried `trim()`, `instr`, `substr` and `replace()` spaces but did not work out. is there any other function?

Comment: I don't quite get what the purpose of this is. What does the length of the string (30 vs. 29 characters) signify, and why does that change your decision to remove 1 or 2 spaces from the string?

Comment: i am using a tool that does not display the column correctly if the string exceeds 28 characters

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `regexp_replace()`.  In this case, the logic is:

```
select regexp_replace(str, ' ([^ ]+) ([0-9]+)$', '\1\2')
from (select 'COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73' as str from dual union all
      select 'COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73x' as str from dual 
     ) x;
```

The regular expression is matching two patterns separated by a space.  The last one consists only of digits and must be at the end of the string.  The one before consists of any non-space characters.  The replacement removes the intermediate space.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87efcd6322ef94dee6b092e6769d098a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain the code . I can understand that the regexp searches for the pattern at the end of the string . ([^ ]+) this searches for whitespace ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function for this purpose:

```
create function reducestr
    (str in varchar2,
     len in number,
     sp in varchar2 := ' '
    ) return varchar2 is
    pos number;
    buf varchar2(4000);
begin
    buf := trim(sp from str);
    loop
        if length(buf) <= len then
            -- great, we're already at or under the target length
            return buf;
        else
            -- find the position of the last occurrence of a space
            pos := instr(buf, sp, -1);
            if pos = 0 then
                -- no more spaces to remove, just truncate the string
                return substr(buf, 1, len);
            else
                -- remove the last space
                buf := substr(buf, 1, pos-1) || substr(buf, pos+1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end loop;
end reducestr;

select reducestr('COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73',28) from dual;

COADC Cathy & Ralph WardJr73
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
declare @String as varchar(100)

Set @String = 'COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73'

declare @ReverseString as varchar(100)
declare @ResultString as varchar(100)
declare @ReverseResult as varchar(100)
set @ReverseString = REVERSE(@String)

select @ReverseString

SELECT @ReverseResult = STUFF(@ReverseString, CHARINDEX(' ', @ReverseString), 1, '')

if len(@String) = 30
    select @ReverseResult = STUFF(@ReverseResult, CHARINDEX(' ', @ReverseResult), 1, '')
if len(@String) = 29
    select @ReverseResult = @ReverseResult

select reverse(@ReverseResult)
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: i am using sql developer . it does not support stuff()